# UIViewPropertyAnimator position reset

Tags: position, progress-bar, uiviewpropertyanimator

I have a slight problem. I'm trying to create animated progress bar like Instagram does. It works correctly in all cases except when I want to present previous item. Breakpoints say that when I switch to previous item, UIViewPropertyAnimator position remains in .end state, so it immediately call its completion and switch "back" to next item. So my question is - when animator done its job, how to reset it's position back to .start and then switch next item?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was related to previous called function. Before moving to the next or previous item I call function which should update all UIProgressView objects through for_in cycle. So when the previous item appeared on the screen, UIProgressView for this item was still .progress = 1.0, UIViewPropertyAnimator had nothing to do, so it called completion block and switch next item.

```
fillProgress(bars: currentStoryItem)
let duration = story.files[currentStoryItem].duration
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
        self.progressBars[self.currentStoryItem].startFillingAnimation(with: duration)
}
```

asyncAfter saved my live)